# Why a custom JS is not recognized in checkout step3 shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, jquery

i tried to add some js `js/custom/custom.js` file to all pages via `local.xml` , the code is present in a source code of the website but he doesn't work in the step 3 [shipping], but when I try to add it manually in `checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml` it works.

Have you an idea to add my file or this custom js code properly.

**local.xml**

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
         <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>custom/custom.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: because it is loaded in with ajax and your script is either loaded before it's targets are loaded?

Comment: Sounds like a load order issue, it's pretty hard to tell without seeing your JS.